# How to get the current Value of ProgressBar in pyQt5?

Tags: python, progress-bar, pyqt5

I'm Learning Pyqt5.
The problem is that i want to get the value of the progressbar in pyqt5

i tried using `self.progressBar.getValue()` or `self.progressBar.getInt()` None of them worked

The actual code is a little big.but never mind. Please help

i just need the syntax for getting the current Value from the progressbar ie: between 1 to 100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to their [documentation](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/api/qtwidgets/qprogressbar.html?highlight=progress#PyQt5.QtWidgets.QProgressBar), the method for getting the value is just `value()`, so in your case, it would be `self.progressBar.value()`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @dustin-we, here is a minimal code example:

```
import sys
import time

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QDialog,
                             QProgressBar, QPushButton)

TIME_LIMIT = 100


class Actions(QDialog):
    """
    Simple dialog that consists of a Progress Bar and a Button.
    Clicking on the button results in the start of a timer and
    updates the progress bar.
    """

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Progress Bar')
        self.progress = QProgressBar(self)
        self.progress.setGeometry(0, 0, 300, 25)
        self.progress.setMaximum(100)
        self.button = QPushButton('Start', self)
        self.button.move(0, 30)
        self.show()

        self.button.clicked.connect(self.onButtonClick)

    def onButtonClick(self):
        count = 0
        while count < TIME_LIMIT:
            count += 1
            time.sleep(0.01)
            self.progress.setValue(count)

            # !! Here is the command you need !!
            print(self.progress.value())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Actions()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks though...my bad...couldn't find such a simple attribute ```value()``` in the stupid internet...